# mule : Does payload order is maintained in Batch Commit of batch processing?

Tags: mule

Is the order of input payload is maintained after batch commit. For eg, consider the input has 3 records , 2nd has a bad data, does the outpu of batch commit will have success for 1st and 3 rd records and failure for the second one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Output from 1st and 3rd record will be committed. Of course there is "Accept Policy" where you can choose to include failed records also.

Check the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35171212/mule-batch-commit-and-records-failures) for a better understanding.